# Global dimension of algebras under field change

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be the collection of all fields (or if this is too large, the collection of all fields with cardinality at most the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$).
Given a quiver algebra $A=FQ/I$ of finite global dimension over some field $F$ where $I$ is an admissible ideal where the coefficients of paths are only the field elements $\pm 1$ (so for example $I=<\alpha \beta, \beta \gamma - \alpha ^2,...>$ is ok but $I=<\alpha^2- 4 \beta \gamma,...>$ not). Then $A$ is actually defined over any field. Write $A_K$ for the quiver algebra over the field $K$.
For a field $K$, define $Ma_K(A) := \sup \{ gldim( A_K) | K \in X  \}$
and $Mi_K(A) := \inf \{ gldim( A_K) | K \in X  \}$ and $\psi(A):=Ma_K(A)-Mi_K(A)$.

Questions:

1. Is $\psi(A)$ always zero in case $A$ is representation-finite (representation-finite algebras should always have an admissible ideal in the above form)?
2. Are there easy examples where one can calculate $\psi(A)$ and $\psi(A)$ is nonzero?
3. Is there an example where $\psi(A)$ is infinite?
4. Is there an example where infinitely values of $gldim(A_K)$ are attained?

Comment: There are examples (not sure about "easy") with $\psi(A)$ arbitrarily large in Prop. 2.5 of Igusa and Zacharia's paper *On the cohomology of incidence algebras of partially ordered sets* [Commun. Algebra 18, No.3, 873-887 (1990).]

Comment: The question is a little unclear. Do you want to think of your algebra as defined over Z and hence you can consider any field or do you want to fix F and consider only extensions K of F?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Over Z should be the right answer, but I usually only look at path algebras over fields.